# How to output Pandas Data to JSON, with specific columns in an array

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to output some results from a Pandas dataframe to JSON, on a row by row basis. I've sorted out the export, that works fine, it's the fine details of making certain columns into an array. For example

```py
Id   customerId   baseValue   targetValue
1    Customer1    482         306
2    Customer2    723         420
3    Customer3    279         161
4    Customer4    162         774
```

I need to export in the style of, for Id 1

```py
{"Id": "1",
 "customerId": "Customer1",
 "results": [{"baseValue": 482},
             {"targetValue": 306}
            ]
}
```

I'm stuck on this bit:

```py
"results": [{"baseValue": 482},
            {"targetValue": 306}
           ]
```

Any pointers?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this to create a "results" column in your dataframe:

```
df.assign(results = df.apply(lambda x: [x[['baseValue','targetValue']].to_dict()], axis=1)).drop(['baseValue','targetValue'], axis=1).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'Id': 1,
  'customerId': 'Customer1',
  'results': [{'baseValue': 482, 'targetValue': 306}]},
 {'Id': 2,
  'customerId': 'Customer2',
  'results': [{'baseValue': 723, 'targetValue': 420}]},
 {'Id': 3,
  'customerId': 'Customer3',
  'results': [{'baseValue': 279, 'targetValue': 161}]},
 {'Id': 4,
  'customerId': 'Customer4',
  'results': [{'baseValue': 162, 'targetValue': 774}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```py
df.to_json(orient="index")
```